# Unable to execute 'gcc-8': No such file or directory error: command 'gcc-8' failed with exit status 1. PySIT package installation

Tags: python, macos, gcc, pip

I am trying to install a package called PySIT to be run with Python, and have followed the instructions on this install page (https://pysit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) using pip on my terminal to install PySIT.

I am using macOS Catalina for this, and have Anaconda installed on my computer.

This is the output I get on my terminal when I run the command: python setup.py install

> gcc-8 -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/KBrindha/anaconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/KBrindha/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Ipysit/solvers/fd_tools -I/Users/KBrindha/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c pysit/solvers/constant_density_acoustic/time/scalar/solvers_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/pysit/solvers/constant_density_acoustic/time/scalar/solvers_wrap.o -O3 -fopenmp -ffast-math
>
> unable to execute 'gcc-8': No such file or directory
> error: command 'gcc-8' failed with exit status 1

Any help on how to bypass this issue or install gcc-8 would be appreciated.
For further information, I have Xcode and Xcode Command Line Tools installed in my computer.
I also have "just" gcc (not gcc-8) installed at /usr/bin/gcc.

Answer (score 0):

The authors [inserted](https://github.com/pysit/pysit/blob/c6de681fbcdbff0b755f4ea5e60ae765fbbfff16/setup.py#L54) fixed names for compilers right into their `setup.py`. This is a bug and I recommend to [report](https://github.com/pysit/pysit/issues) it.

Meanwhile you can clone the repository or [download source code](https://pypi.org/project/pysit/#files), extract it, edit `setup.py` and remove or replace these fixed names. Then build with the command `pip install .`